# Numpy module only works at one of terminal or vscode [python3.10][mac m1 pro]

Tags: python-3.x, macos, numpy, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

I'm trying to use numpy module in python 3.10
Since I use vscode, I installed numpy module in the vscode terminal at first.
Then, when I tried to test some simple numpy calculation thru my local terminal, this error occurred.

```
<error>
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
```

> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
> - The NumPy version is: "1.24.2"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.

> Original error was:
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried:
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need
> 'x86_64')),
> '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file),
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need
> 'x86_64'))

Thus, I uninstalled numpy and re-installed it through my local terminal.
Then, I could import and use numpy well in my local terminal, but now I can't run python file including numpy in vscode with showing the error above in the vscode terminal.

So I always uninstall and reinstall numpy module to use it just because of difference of the platform. I want to use it in the both situation... what should I do?

Comment: You have multiple copies of Python, but they are compiled for different architectures.  You either want to get compatible versions or check out virtual environments to separate out the libraries

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn't know my m1 local terminal's default arch was i386! I will change it :)

Comment: I'm a Linux user so don't know how easy it is to make this this change.  If it's non-trivial it might be worth posting an answer to your question to help other people, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75425266/1358308