# How to change i386 arch to arm64 in vscode terminal?

Tags: macos, x86, arm, apple-m1, arch

How to change i386 arch to arm64 in vscode terminal? *m2 pro silicon*. I asked 'cause **`yarn`** and **`npm`** dosen't work in vscode terminal but perfectly work in external terminals (iterm2, Terminal)

[vscode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeQ1M.png)

[default terminal mac os](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd1lF.png)

[Not Rosetta in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTI85.png)

[Not Rosetta in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utOHZ.png)

[When I start terminal in vscode it's use intel (i386)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/923LZ.png)

I'd like to change arch in my vscode terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the terminal inside Visual Studio code to use the non-Rosetta one i.e. have it use the arm64 one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781379/how-do-i-change-the-terminal-inside-visual-studio-code-to-use-the-non-rosetta-on)

Answer (score 1):

Use the exec arch command, e.g.:

```
$ echo $TERM_PROGRAM      
vscode
$ arch              
i386
$ exec arch -arm64 $SHELL 
$ arch                   
arm64
$ exec arch -x86_64 $SHELL
$ arch
i386
$
```